# Displaying Most NODE_OPTIONs are not supported in packaged apps error after npm command

Tags: cypress, npm-start

*"Most NODE_OPTIONs are not supported in packaged apps. See documentation for more details."* error is displaying in the vs code console after I enter the npm.
This issue comes up after I installed cypress version 9.4.1. The code is running fine but every time I run the code this error message comes up.

Why this issue is displaying and can someone explain to me how to fix this, please?

Comment: You did not ask any question.. What is the point you want to make here?

Comment: Need to know how to fix this issue

Comment: Without further details on your test execution this will certainly be difficult

Comment: I had similar issue, i reverted back to 9.2 version, working fine for me now. try reverting to previous version it mite help you ->  npm install cypress@9.2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem
But the point is that I use Angular version 14

I run the command `ng e2e` to solve this problem
Then I selected cypress among the suggested options in the command line

Comment: ng e2e is only for angular

Comment: Yes, I have mentioned it.

This command created a structure that would not normally be created and automatically installed everything I need for testing.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error with javascript debug terminal. If your terminal commands work on a js debug terminal. You can try to change your terminal. Gitbash solved my problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).